Windows 10 - Virtual desktops useless after a fresh reinstall
first of all, note that by virtual desktops I'm not talking about physical monitors; I only have my laptop's screen.
I spent lots of hours comparing 2 laptops registry (SVN diff) and settings and I can't figure this out.
Here is something that used to work:

Pin apps A, B, C, D & E to the taskbar
Press Windows+1 & Windows+2 to quickly open apps A & B
Press Windows+Tab to create a 2nd virtual desktop
Press Windows+1 & Windows+3 to open apps A & C in the 2nd virtual desktop
Press Windows+Tab to create a 3rd virtual desktop
Press Windows+4 & Windows+5 to open apps D & E in the 3rd virtual desktop
Navigate through the workspaces with Windows+CTRL+Left/Right
The taskbar in the 1st virtual desktop only show A & B as being opened
The taskbar in the 2nd virtual desktop only show A & C as being opened
The taskbar in the 3rd virtual desktop only show D & E as being opened

Now after formatting C: and reinstalling (because of a crash), it doesn't work anymore and causes 2 things:

At step #4, if I press Windows+1, instead of opening app A in the 2nd virtual desktop, it'll navigate back to the 1st virtual desktop to bring app A in focus. To go around this, I have to open the apps via the start menu or command line so they appear in the 2nd virtual desktop.
Once I manage to get all setuped correctly, now all 3 virtual desktops show all apps as being opened, which is really confusing and kills the purpose. It's like if I physically put stuff on 2 desks in an office and they're in quantum superposition.

My actual use case is I'm a web programmer and we work on multiple projects at a time, so I could have:

Virtual desktop 1 with Outlook and Teams opened
Virtual desktop 2 with VSCode & localhost browser for some project
Virtual desktop 3 with VSCode & localhost browser for some other project
Virtual desktop 4 with VSCode & localhost browser for yet another project
Virtual desktop 5 with browser & presentations opened for a live demo for a customer

one time I was sharing my screen for a presentation (let's say virtual desktop 5) and when I tried to open the browser to show their new app, I got sent to another virtual desktop (say #2) where the browser was already opened, and they saw things they didn't have to.
Current version is 10.0.19045. Before reinstalling I had exported the full registry, so I also checked lines containing "taskbar" to compare, but there are just too many and I couldn't find something that seemed to be related to this issue. I feel like it's something in [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] but they only seem to relate to expanding/collapsing apps like we find in Windows+I settings under Personalization/Task bar...
Thanks
